# Auto-register GitLab runner

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that sets up Gitlab, Container Registry and a Gitlab Runner.

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/redis:latest
    command:
    - --loglevel warning
    volumes:
    - redis:/var/lib/redis:Z

  postgresql:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/postgresql:9.5-3
    volumes:
    - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql:Z
    environment:
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production
    - DB_EXTENSION=pg_trgm

  gitlab:
    restart: always
    image: sameersbn/gitlab:10.1.1
    volumes:
    - gitlab-data:/home/git/data:Z
    - gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab
    - ./certs:/certs
    depends_on:
    - redis
    - postgresql
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "2222:22"
    external_links:
    - "registry:registry"
    environment:
    - DEBUG=false

    - DB_ADAPTER=postgresql
    - DB_HOST=postgresql
    - DB_PORT=5432
    - DB_USER=gitlab
    - DB_PASS=password
    - DB_NAME=gitlabhq_production

    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - REDIS_PORT=6379

    - GITLAB_HTTPS=false # <---
    - SSL_SELF_SIGNED=true # <---

    - GITLAB_HOST=192.168.99.100 # <---
    - GITLAB_PORT=80
    - GITLAB_SSH_PORT=2222
    - GITLAB_SHELL_SSH_PORT=2222
    - GITLAB_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_DB_KEY_BASE=secret
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret
    - GITLAB_SECRETS_OTP_KEY_BASE=secret

    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_ENABLED=true
    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_HOST=localhost # <---
    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_PORT=4567
    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_API_URL=https://localhost:4567/ # Internal address to the registry, will be used by GitLab to directly communicate with API.
    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_CERT_PATH=/certs/localhost-auth.crt # <---
    - GITLAB_REGISTRY_KEY_PATH=/certs/localhost-auth.key # <---

# Read here --> https://hub.docker.com/r/sameersbn/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/
  runner:
    restart: always
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    external_links:
    - "gitlab:gitlab" # <---
    environment:
    - CI_SERVER_URL=http://192.168.99.100:80/ci/
    - RUNNER_TOKEN=1XoJuQeyyN3EZxAt7pkn # < ------------------- different every time
    - RUNNER_DESCRIPTION=default_runner
    - RUNNER_EXECUTOR=shell

  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2.4.1
    ports:
    - "4567:5000" # <---
    volumes:
    - registry-data:/var/lib/registry
    - ./certs:/certs
    external_links:
    - "gitlab:gitlab" # <---
    environment:
    - REGISTRY_LOG_LEVEL=info
    - REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true
    - REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry

    - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_REALM=http://localhost/jwt/auth # <---
    - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_SERVICE=container_registry
    - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ISSUER=localhost
    - REGISTRY_AUTH_TOKEN_ROOTCERTBUNDLE=/certs/localhost-auth.crt # <---

    - SSL_REGISTRY_KEY_PATH=/certs/localhost-auth.key # <---
    - SSL_REGISTRY_CERT_PATH=/certs/localhost-auth.crt # <---

    - REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/localhost-auth.crt # <---
    - REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/localhost-auth.key # <---
    - REGISTRY_HTTP_SECRET=secret

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "/opt/portainer:/data"

volumes:
    gitlab-data:
    gitlab-logs:
    postgresql:
    redis:
    registry-data:
```

The problem is that the runner is not registered and I have to do it every time manually (not succeeded yet though). I would like to be registered automatically to the Gitlab server with the auto-generated token so I [or the arbitrary dev that would use the `docker-compose.yml` file] do not care about that.

I am trying to find a way to grab the token and feed it to the runner. Is it possible in any way?

Comment: I found this [https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24030] , with the last comment being 1 week old , so i guess they will add it soon ...

Comment: Above link is broken, here's a clickable one: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24030  Issue looks active indeed

Comment: Where are env variables for runner like RUNNER_TOKEN documented? I do not see official image gitlab/gitlab-runner supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either (1) mount your `/etc/gitlab-runner` directory and keep it persistent or (2) create an entrypoint script that registers the runner every time the container starts.

For example, you may have an entrypoint script like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# entrypoint.sh
gitlab-runner register \
  --non-interactive \
  --url "${CI_SERVER_URL}/" \
  --registration-token "${RUNNER_TOKEN}" \
  --executor "${RUNNER_EXECUTOR}" \
  --descritpion="${RUNNER_DESCRIPTION}" \
  --config="/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml"

# call original gitlab-runner entrypoint with CMD args
exec /usr/bin/dumb-init /entrypoint "$@"
```

And a dockerfile for the runner like this:

```
FROM gitlab/gitlab-runner:v14.8.2

COPY entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Need to redefine original CMD provided by the parent image after setting ENTRYPOINT
CMD ["run", "--user=gitlab-runner", "--working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner"]
```

This is just one way of expressing the solution. In principle, you don't need to custom-build the image -- you could make an equivalent `entrypoint:` key in your compose file and skip the custom dockerfile.